# BMP-format Where are 2 bytes?

Tags: c++, bmp

I have got a .bmp picture(24-bits). It is small(65x65) and its size is equal to 12796 bytes.
But let is compute:

- 54 bytes for header
- 65*65*3 bytes for pixels
- 1*65 bytes for padding for each line.

---

== 12794
Where can be 2 extra bytes?
And second question: do I use correct formula for computin padding?

```
int padding = (4 - bmp.width % 4) % 4 * sizeof(PIXEL);
```

I use this structure:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct BMP {
    int8_t id0;
    int8_t id1;
    int32_t filesize;        
    int32_t reserved;     //int32  == 2 int16
    int32_t headersize;      
    int32_t infoSize;        
    int32_t width;           
    int32_t height;           
    int16_t biPlanes;       
    int16_t bits;            
    int32_t biCompression;   
    int32_t biSizeImage;     
    int32_t biXPelsPerMeter; 
    int32_t biYPelsPerMeter; 
    int32_t biClrUsed;       
    int32_t biClrImportant;  
};
#pragma pack(pop)
    
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct PIXEL {
    char B;
    char G;
    char R;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Well since no one has an answer, I want to confirm that it should be 12794 bytes. Because your image width is 65 and each pixel is 24 bytes, each row should be 65 * 3 = 195 bytes and closest multiple of 4 is 196 which means there is one byte of padding at each row. Final size is 54 (header) + 196 * 65 = 12794.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#/media/File:BMPfileFormat.png shows an optional gap between header and image data, so I would look at the value you read in `headersize` (in the image `File Offset to PixelArray`) and make sure it is 54 and not 56.

Comment: Another option, provided that you made it yourself, is to put specific colors in the four corners of your image and then manually look in the image data and locate them. That should enable you to figure out where your 2 extra bytes are hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bmp.width` is in *pixels*. A BMP row is padded to 4 *bytes*. To get from pixels to bytes, multiply it by bitsPerPixel/8. Then pad that to 4.

Something like this:

```
int rowSizeInBytes = ((bmp.bits * bmp.width + 31) / 32) * 4;
```

Then, you should not assume header size is 54, take it from `bmp.headersize` instead.

Assuming a header size of 54, for a 65x65 24-bit image we get 196 bytes per row * 65 rows + 54 = 12794. So it would mean your file has 2 extra bytes at the end.

Comment: Yeah. My teaher said, that sometimes bmp files are created with 2 extra zero-value bytes at the end. He said it is more convenient for BMP-reader-program.) I think, that it also pads all file size to 4, because 12794 is not divisible by 4, but 12796 is so.

Comment: Yes, could be, but also check that `bmp.headersize` really contains 54.

Comment: I`ve had checked. Contains exactly 54 bytes.